# Queue lookup in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, redhat, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

My connection factory:

```xml
<connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
    <connectors>
        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
    </entries>
</connection-factory>
```

Destination Queue:

```xml
<jms-queue name="TestQueue">
    <entry name="java:jboss/jms/queue/TestQueue"/>
    <durable>true</durable>
</jms-queue>
```

I have written the below Java sample code to look-up the queue defined in JBoss EAP 6.4, but I'm getting an exception on looking up the queue. The connection factory look up is working

```java
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
qc = qcf.createQueueConnection();

qc.setExceptionListener(this);
qsess = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("/jms/queue/TestQueue");
qsndr = qsess.createSender(queue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found out the issue. I need to specify the fully qualified name otherwise it won't work. Fixed by using this code:

```
     Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/jms/queue/TestQueue");
```